# Как разобрать такой массив?

Tags: php

Привет всем. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разобрать такой массив.

```
Array ( [request_data] => Array ( [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [account_id] => 4024023 [member_since] => 1331229211 [banned] => [role_id] => recruit [role] => аНаОаВаОаБбаАаНаЕб [name] => 89514542144 ) [1] => Array ( [account_id] => 4678395 [member_since] => 1331557929 [banned] => [role_id] => recruit [role] => аНаОаВаОаБбаАаНаЕб [name] => Alligator164 ) [2] => Array ( [account_id] => 4243933 [member_since] => 1329743557 [banned] => [role_id] => recruit [role] => аНаОаВаОаБбаАаНаЕб [name] => antoha20a ) [3] => Array ( [account_id] => 1525511 [member_since] => 1330846021 [banned] => [role_id] => recruit [role] => аНаОаВаОаБбаАаНаЕб [name] => barnaul_ ) [4] => Array ( [account_id] => 739432 [member_since] => 1326646880 [banned] => [role_id] => recruiter [role] => аВаЕбаБаОаВбаИаК [name] => BlackArrow25 ) [5] => Array ( [account_id] => 3791323 [member_since] => 1329980245 [banned] => [role_id] => private [role] => баОаЛаДаАб [name] => deaer ) [6] => Array ( [account_id] => 847750 [member_since] => 1331135412 [banned] => [role_id] => recruit [role] => аНаОаВаОаБбаАаНаЕб [name] => deloput )) [total_count] => 30 [filtered_count] => 30 [offset] => 0 [echo] => 0 ) [result] => success )
```

Необходимо вытащить только значения ключей name. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @icedev, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если тебе требуется вытащить только name, то наверное вот так:

```
foreach ( $data['request_data']['items'] as $item ) {
  echo $item['name'];
}
```

Вроде ни чего не напутал.

Comment: Бинго. Все заработало. Больше спасибо.  

Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = (); // твой массив
echo $array[name][0];
echo $array[name][1];
echo $array[name][2];
```

и т.д.

Comment: Так пробывал.  в браузер вообще ничего не выводится.
Вот это и есть сам массив.
-------------
Array ( [request_data] => Array ( [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [account_id] => 4024023 [member_since] => 1331229211 [banned] => [role_id] => recruit [role] => аНаОаВаОаБбаАаНаЕб [name] => 89514542144 ) [1] => Array ( [account_id] => 4678395 [member_since]
и т.д
------------
Находится в одной переменной $data.

Какие еще предложения?

Comment: `$array[request_data][items][0][name]`

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос состоит. Это обычный многомерный массив, главное не запутаться во вложениях.

Comment: Мне кажеться, что этот "массив" у него в виде строки))))) то ест ьтакой как он приводит тут.

Comment: Это скорее похоже на var_dump() или на print_r() переменной $data, в которую он получает массив.

Comment: Нет, не в виде строки. 

$array[request_data][items][0][name]  // тоже результата не дало

Answer (score 1):

С версии **PHP 5.5.0** можно делать такие операции гораздо проще и быстрее, с помощью функции **array_column**.

```
   $result =  array_column($arr['request_data']['items'], 'name');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php